# How to find the traces of IPC or CPI

Tags: kernel, profiler

I am looking to find the traces of IPC or CPI of the applications. For example at 1k instructions the IPC is this, at 2k instructions the IPC is this, so on and so forth. I can also work with the cycles or specific time interval instead of the instructions.

Any other tool that you can think of that I can use for this particular purpose.

I have intel xeon and intel atom to work with.

Regards,

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a benchmark tool rather than a profiler. Are you planning to analyze one specific application in order to give advice on the hardware or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It would help to know what system you're on.  Linux and Windows have pretty distinct tools for this - I would assume MacOS too.

Comment: I am working on linux 13.10 ubuntu